# python 2.4 logging - dynamic log file name inside loop

Tags: python, loops, logging

I'm trying to write to a separate log file which is created inside a loop using basicConfig. So far I managed to create only one log file which has all the subsequent logging calls. Am I missing something trivial here? I checked the docs it had hints about filemode but nothing else.

```
import logging


class MultipleInstancesStarter:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


    def startMany(self):
        objs = [Main(str(i)) for i in xrange(1, 10)]
        print objs
        for obj in objs:
            obj._start()


class Main:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.index = i


    def _start(self):
        name = self.index
        logging.basicConfig(
                        filename="log_" + name + ".log",
                        filemode="w",
                        format="%(asctime)s -  %(levelname)s - %(filename)s:%(module)s:%(lineno)d - %(message)s",
                        level=logging.DEBUG)

        logging.debug("%s Message Debug" % name)
        logging.info("%s Message Info" % name)
        logging.error("%s Message Error" % name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MultipleInstancesStarter().startMany()
```

This creates only log_1.log with log entries from 2nd iteration as well. I tried creating an object outside the loop and it creates a separate file no problem though as shown below.

```
def startMany(self):
    obj2 = Main("sample")
    obj2._start()

    objs = [Main(str(i)) for i in xrange(1, 10)]
    print objs
    for obj in objs:
        obj._start()
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong though, any help would be appreciated. Cheers

Comment: what is the output of `print objs` ?

Comment: [<__main__.Main instance at 0xb777056c>, <__main__.Main instance at 0xb7770a8c>, <__main__.Main instance at 0xb7770b4c>, <__main__.Main instance at 0xb7770bec>, <__main__.Main instance at 0xb777918c>, <__main__.Main instance at 0xb77794ac>, <__main__.Main instance at 0xb7523cec>, <__main__.Main instance at 0xb7523d0c>, <__main__.Main instance at 0xb7523d2c>] - they all look like different references

Comment: My understanding is that basicConfig must be called only once. Once it is configured, the logging module will have handlers, and the doc says `This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured for it.`. You probably need to call `logging.shutdown` after your logging to a file is done, in order to flush the handlers and allow logging to be reconfigured with an other file.

Comment: (bottom line: call `logging.shutdown()` as the last line of `_start`)

Comment: Hmmm that didn't do anything either. I still get all the logging calls in one file. I can use some other config if basicConfig won't do the job. Cheers

Comment: `logging.getLogger('').handlers = []` ? (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167348/python-logging-does-not-work-at-all)

Comment: Also, there is this question that seems related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754126/python-logger-dynamic-filename

Comment: You need to use loggers. A basicConfig will work for only one file (even though I never tried your case before). You should get create one handler per instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
import logging


class MultipleInstancesStarter:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def startMany(self):
        objs = [Main(str(i)) for i in xrange(1, 10)]
        print objs
        for obj in objs:
            obj._start()


class Main:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.index = i

    def _start(self):
        name = self.index
        logger = logging.getLogger('%s-%s' % (__name__, self.index))
        handler = logging.FileHandler('log_%s.log' % name)
        log_format = ('%(asctime)s -  %(levelname)s - %(filename)s:'
                      '%(module)s:%(lineno)d - %(message)s')
        formatter = logging.Formatter(log_format)
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(handler)

        logger.debug("%s Message Debug" % name)
        logger.info("%s Message Info" % name)
        logger.error("%s Message Error" % name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MultipleInstancesStarter().startMany()
```

This it the output (I used tail on the log files):

> ==> log_1.log <== 2013-11-12 21:08:15,866 -  ERROR - test.py:test:31 - 1 Message Error
>
> ==> log_2.log <== 2013-11-12 21:08:15,866 -  ERROR - test.py:test:31 - 2 Message Error
>
> ==> log_3.log <== 2013-11-12 21:08:15,866 -  ERROR - test.py:test:31 - 3 Message Error
>
> ==> log_4.log <== 2013-11-12 21:08:15,866 -  ERROR - test.py:test:31 - 4 Message Error
>
> ==> log_5.log <== 2013-11-12 21:08:15,866 -  ERROR - test.py:test:31 - 5 Message Error
>
> ==> log_6.log <== 2013-11-12 21:08:15,866 -  ERROR - test.py:test:31 - 6 Message Error
>
> ==> log_7.log <== 2013-11-12 21:08:15,867 -  ERROR - test.py:test:31 - 7 Message Error
>
> ==> log_8.log <== 2013-11-12 21:08:15,867 -  ERROR - test.py:test:31 - 8 Message Error
>
> ==> log_9.log <== 2013-11-12 21:08:15,867 -  ERROR - test.py:test:31 - 9 Message Error

Basically, if the logging part becomes a bit tricky, use different loggers, one for each instance in that case. A [good article](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html) to read on Python documentation

**EDIT:** I forgot to add the log level. To do so, you can add this before adding the handler to the logger

```
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```